# Access phpmyadmin with codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a Codeigniter application that works fine except that I have no access to phpmyadmin anymore. I used to access to phpmyadmin with mydomain.com/phpmyadmin, but, with codeigniter installed, it now gives me a 404 error  and it makes sense because I'm rewriting the route like mydomain/index.php/phpmyadmin in my .htaccess. The thing is, when I exclude phpmyadmin from the rewrite rule, mydomain/phpmyadmin brings me to the default controller.

I'm running out of ideas to access phpmyadmin. Here's my .htaccess :

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets/|robots\.txt|sitemap\.xml|phpmyadmin)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#some RedirectMatch like : (if I remove them it doesn't change anything)
RedirectMatch 301 /en/index.php http://www.mydomain.com/defaultController
```

Here is my folder structure :

```
/CodeIgniter/application
/CodeIgniter/system
/public/assets
/public/phpmyadmin
/public/.htaccess
/public/index.php    
/public/sitemap.xml
```

The same behaviour appears when I try mydomain.com/assets, I'm throwed back to the default controller.

Does anybody know how should I configure everything to have access to phpmyadmin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of the forward-slash:

<strike>`|phpmyadmin/)`</strike>

```
|phpmyadmin)
```

---

Please update your question with the folder structure; e.g.

```
/var/www/public_html/.htaccess
/var/www/public_html/CodeIgniter/
/var/www/public_html/CodeIgniter/.htaccess
/var/www/public_html/CodeIgniter/application
/var/www/public_html/CodeIgniter/system
/var/www/public_html/assets
```

Comment: Is it in a folder called `phpmyadmin` alongside your CodeIgniter `index.php`?

Comment: NP. Is that your entire `.htaccess` or is there other stuff in there too?

Comment: No I also have `Options -Indexes`, `RewriteEngine on` and a bunch of RedirectMatch like `RedirectMatch 301 old/url/from/old/website http:\\www.mydomain.com` but nothing that could redirect something like phpmyadmin I think (I checked for phpmyadmin and *)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the entire `.htaccess` and also add your directory structure.

Comment: Nop still not working..actually it also prevented the rewrite on all url so I couldn't have any pages without the index.php in the middle with this solution.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I deleted that. Please update question with entire `.htaccess`

Comment: That 301 hints that there are other folders involved `/en/` and you said you have a CodeIgniter folder. Please clarify your folder structure as explained in my answer. Please include ALL `.htaccess`.

Comment: These 301 are just a way to redirect users who are still using the urls refering to the old website. The structure has changed, there is no other folders in the public directory. I'll update the folder structure. I can't put all the .htaccess sorry, but I can tell you that if I erase all the redirectMatch I have, the same problem remains, mydomain.com/phpmyadmin still redirects me to the default controller.

Comment: ...you can sanitize the `.htaccess`. Also, it's still not clear what is going on. Which is your actual directory root? `public`? `www`? Are you getting a CI 404? Or an apache 404?

Comment: The root is the public directory. CodeIgniter files are in the CodeIgniter directory that is not in the public directory. I get a CI 404 when I don't put phpmyadmin in the .htaccess, I get an Apache 404 when I spell it wrong in the .htaccess and try to access it that way (for example, mydomain.com/phpMyAdmin gives me an apache error).

Comment: I checked the syntax of my .htaccess with an online tester, it was good. I tested the .htaccess with another tool online to see what http://www.mydomain.com/phpmyadmin gives me and it gave me the same thing. So I guess the redirection comes from codeigniter somewhere..

Comment: Yeah but it should't -- the request shouldn't even get to CI to be redirected...What happens when it is spelled correctly and you try to access the URL correctly? Apache or CI 404? Also, to make sure we're not going crazy, can you blank out the `.htaccess` and try to access phpmyadmin?

Comment: Ok...now I'm confused. I blanked the .htaccess and it worked, so I started to put it back line by line to see where was the problem...and I got to the end of the file without problem and now it works...! For what it worths I added `RewriteBase /` before my rules a couple of minutes ago, but it didn't work until now. I'll edit my question and mark it as solved. Weird....thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: Good job -- that's a good way to attack the problem. Glad you got it working.